# Passing auto properties as ref

Tags: c#, .net, automatic-properties

The C# compiler doesn't allow this. What's the reason for this? And what workaround I can use?

Basically I need to swap some values around, but don't wanna have the same swapping code all over.

Comment: Ravadre's answer is solid.  If you can provide more details on why you think you need ref treatment of properties, perhaps the crowd can provide you a workaround.

Comment: It's because I need to swap some values around. Like x and y for instance.

Comment: @Joan: I'd suggest not using automatic properties. This feature was introduce as a syntactic sugar, not as a must-use feature. If situation require that you need to access the variable itself, as well as you property for clean encapsulation, you might consider going "the standard way".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Properties, in general are just methods, so it would be strange if you could just "get reference to them", as no one can be sure, that you are referring to just a variable. I don't think there's a quick and nice workaround other that not using auto-properties in this case.

I'm omitting the idea of using reflection to get to those variables under the hood, as it wouldn't make much sense in this case.